# Question about creating table using psycopg2's sql module

Tags: python, postgresql

'''

```
host = "localhost"
user = "postgres"
password = "Lall1739!@#"
port = "5432"
dbname = "snp500"
con_form = "host={0} user={1} password={2} port={3} dbname={4}".format(host, user, password, port, dbname)

con = psycopg2.connect(con_form)
cur = con.cursor()

components_name, components_prices, components_fetch_dates = fetch_investing_snp500_components_datas()

for component_name in components_name:
    table_name = component_name
    cur.execute(
        query=sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE %s"), 
        vars=(sql.Identifier(table_name))
    )
```

'''

> TypeError: 'Identifier' object does not support indexing

It's also not a good idea to use Python string interpolation to build the query string.

So I am trying to write a query using the sql module.
What exactly are the benefits of writing a query using the sql module and why am I getting a Type error?

Comment: What is `sql` in your code?

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak `sql` is [`psycopg2.sql`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html).

Comment: The benefits and proper usage are spelled out in the docs [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `execute` is used for *parameter* substitution (.i.e. string literals), whereas you want to substitute *identifiers* (i.e. table names). Use [SQL.format()](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.SQL.format) for that:

```py
cur.execute(
    query=sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE {table}").format(
        table=sql.Identifier(table_name),
    ), 
)
```